# Get the TID from taxonomy view

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming, views

I am using one of the packaged views that comes with the Views module titled 'Taxonomy term' to handle what product looks like when someone searches the taxonomy. Is there a way to grab the tid of the term being viewed from the theme page or node template file?

Edit: Maybe I should explain what I am trying to do. I have a couple of selectmenu (also created by views) that get the terms from a certain taxonomy grouping. When a user selects an option, it takes them to the Taxonomy term view. I need to be able to grab the tid so that I can make a new select menu out of the choice they made.

Application: Let's say a I have a bunch of products in a number of brands. Someone picks a brand. I need a new select menu created for all the product in that brand.

If there is a way to do this in views, that's fine, but if i had the tid, I could just make a module or a function that creates the select menu.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.

Comment: Well. Maybe. Is there any documentation on this module? I installed it and tried to use it, but it didn't change anything. And I can't find a how-to anywhere

Comment: I didn't myself used this module, but here is a documentation: [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/node/262835)